# Fix the Self-learner "Go get it" link

Tags: bug, badges

So now the "Go get it" link of the "Self-learner" badge leads to a page of the following custom search:

```
user:XXXXXX is:question hasaccepted:no closed:no
```

but the badge requires the question to have the score 3 or more. So I propose that the link should lead to a page of this custom search:

```
user:3995261 is:question hasaccepted:no closed:no score:3
```

Comment: The answer you post needs a score of 3 or more, not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *question* does not need to have a score of 3 or greater; your *answer* does. From the [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258):

> #### Self-Learner
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Provide an *answer with a score of 3* or more to your own question
> - Works on community wiki answers

Comment: I see, thanks. It's just misleading short description: "Answer your own question with score of 3 or more".

Comment: @YakovL it is ambiguous indeed (like is often the case with short descriptions). The *with score of 3 or more* part of the sentence applies to the verb *answer*.

Comment: May be "Answer your own question and get score of 3 or more" would be slightly better.

Comment: @YakovL [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181111/editing-the-self-learner-badge-description) are some other suggestions.